# Any differences between "modify" and "change"?

Tags: word-choice, differences

In the context of sharing flight irregularity information to the passengers, are there any differences between "Your flight has been modified" and " Your flight has been changed"?

My understanding is that change means to become something completely different, while modify means to make partial changes. I would prefer "modified" if the flight is being rescheduled to a different date but with same flight number and route. Appreciate your suggestions to find the proper word.

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot possibly say which is better for the airline industry in given circumstances. But "change" certainly suggests a more radical and complete alteration to "modify". One "changes" one's address when one moves home. But the design of a car gets "modified" if, for example, the manufacturer decides to install a larger engine. But one might "modify" a car by "changing" a key feature - such as the engine.

Comment: The use of **either** one of these words would make one feel that it is intended to obscure what is actually happening, rather than honestly and clearly convey the relevant information. What one needs to know is **what** about one's flight has been changed/modified, not merely that something about it has been changed/modified. Instead of saying that the flight has been changed/modified, one should say something like 'Your flight will depart seven hours later than scheduled' or 'Your flight will be on a smaller plane'.

Comment: @jsw29 Sorry if I wasn't being too clear. The updated flight information should be followed by the said sentence, e.g. Flight UA123 on 20JAN has been modified to UA123 on JAN21 from LAX 12:00 to SFO 15:00.

Comment: @minetheirs, in such a case, it would be much clearer to just say something like 'Flight UA123 on 20 Jan. has been cancelled; you have been rebooked on flight UA123 on 21 Jan.'. The original flight has been neither changed nor modified; it simply won't take place. If one really wants to use one of these words, it may be OK to say that the passenger's booking or reservation has been changed.

Comment: I would expect a modification of a flight to be something comparatively minor. For example a delay of 30 minutes or less to the departure time, a change in the type of plane, possibly a change from a plane with business class accommodation  to one without. The last would only affect business class passengers but could affect them quite severely. They would certainly demand refunds. A change to the flight (or rather to the booking) would involve rescheduling, possibly flying to or from another airport and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot possibly say which is better for the airline industry in given circumstances. It would have to depend on context. If I arrived at the airport to be told that my flight had been "modified" such that it would now be leaving the following day, I could imagine becoming annoyed and suggesting that it had been "changed" - or worse "cancelled".

**But "change" certainly suggests a more radical and complete alteration to "modify".**

One "changes" one's address when one moves home. But the design of a car gets "modified" if, for example, the manufacturer decides to install a larger engine.